# Toilet not flushing properly

Tags: bathroom

I have two toilets, the one upstairs flushes fine. The one in the basement does not.  The basement one is the issue.

We have a septic system, we have used an auger to in, we put strong cleaner to remove any debris.  However, the toilet gurgles have the water goes down after flushing but not everything goes out.  We poured additional water in it to see how fast it was going out and appears good.  Just flushing causes the water to rise high, but no suction.

Recent flooding in area. HELP!!

Comment: You'll probably need to determine whether your sewer is backed up in general. See if you can locate a cleanout and assess that.

Comment: Not really enough information here to make much in the way of definitive comments.  Two things come to mind, however.  First, are you sure there is no blockage in the waste line between the toilet and the septic?  Just dumping "cleaner" down it will not fix a blockage.  The best approach is to get someone with a snake camera to check it for you.  Secondly, is the septic properly installed and working?  If the drainage field is not properly drained itself it will backup during periods of heavy rain.  Get a professional to check it for you.

Comment: Is the basement toilet vented properly?  I remember a similar problem with a basement toilet where the vent stack got blocked causing the problem.